# MySQL Trigger After insert not actually after insert?

Tags: mysql, triggers, foreign-keys, constraints

I've written a trigger to insert a record into an invoice table every time a prescription is written for a patient. The row inserted to the invoice table by the trigger uses a foreign key from the prescriptions table. But i'm getting the error:

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`invoice`, CONSTRAINT `PrescriptionID` FOREIGN KEY (`PrescriptionID`)

So despite the fact the trigger time is 'AFTER INSERT' my relationship fails because the record doesn't exist yet.

Is there a way around this or am I missing something?

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `test`.`prescription_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `prescription` 
FOR EACH ROW begin
    INSERT INTO invoice (PrescriptionID, AmountDue)    
    SELECT pr.PrescriptionID, CASE
        WHEN pa.PrescriptionCodeID = 'FF' THEN '0'
        WHEN pa.PrescriptionCodeID = 'MM' THEN '8'
        END
    FROM prescription AS pr
    JOIN patients AS pa
    ON pa.PatientID = pr.PatientID
    WHERE pr.prescriptionID = NEW.prescriptionID;
END
```

Comment: The trigger `BEFORE_INSERT` the `SELECT` does not return value because the record has not been inserted, however, the trigger `AFTER_INSERT` in the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c61e/1) example works as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I've amended the title as I meant 'After' The code example above isn't working in my database.

Comment: How did you fix this?  I am having a similar issue.

Comment: Sorry, I never fixed it.